# owl-carousel при изменении размера начинают отображаться все итемы,и карусель не работает

Tags: html, css, scss, owl-carousel

Доброго времени суток.
Установил owl-carousel,опыт работы с этим плагином сводился к парочке раз.Но без проблем.В этот раз столкнулся с проблемой такого характера : 
При изменении размера страницы либо смены ориентации на телефоне,слайдер перестает работать,и все итемы выстраиваются как строчно блочные элементы.Перезагрузка страницы с новым изображением не помогает.
Может кто-то может подсказать в чем заключается проблема.

Скрнишоты :

https://puu.sh/w8gHa/a52a0315b2.png  -- 320px Работает как надо.
https://puu.sh/w8gJc/e2308f34ca.png  -- 570px Ломается

Начинает ломаться от 480px до 1200px.

Не могу понять из-за чего это происходит :/Итемы вложенные в слайдер резиновые,должны занимать всю ширину.

Код
HTML

```
 <section class="reviews">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <p class="section-title">Отзывы наших учеников</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                        <div class="owl-carousel">
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="slide-wrap">
                                    <div class="review-photo"><img src="images/review.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    <div class="reviewer-name">
                                        <p>Соломатина Наталья</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="hr"></span>
                                    <div class="review-content">
                                        <p>Хочу поблагодарить ProKurs и Алену за проведенные курсы повышения квалификации. Эти уроки помогли мне преодолеть трудности. Уроки проходили в дружеской и непосредственной атмосфере, что способствовало хорошему усвоению материала и мотивировало на дальнейшие занятия. Алена всегда находила интересные темы для обсуждения.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                <div class="slide-wrap">
                                    <div class="review-photo"><img src="images/review.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    <div class="reviewer-name">
                                        <p>Соломатина Наталья</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="hr"></span>
                                    <div class="review-content">
                                        <p>Хочу поблагодарить ProKurs и Алену за проведенные курсы повышения квалификации. Эти уроки помогли мне преодолеть трудности. Уроки проходили в дружеской и непосредственной атмосфере, что способствовало хорошему усвоению материала и мотивировало на дальнейшие занятия. Алена всегда находила интересные темы для обсуждения.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
})
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    items: 1,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:1,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
    }
})
```

SCSS

```
section.reviews {
    background-image: url('../images/middle_bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    color: $white;
    p.section-title {
        color: inherit;
    }
    div.slide-wrap {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        div.review-photo {
            img {
                width: 164px;
                height: 164px;
                border: 10px solid #606161;
                background-color: #606161;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        }
        div.reviewer-name {
            font-family: 'Times New Roman' , sans-serif;
            font-style: italic;
            font-size: 1.57em;
            padding-top: 8px;
        }
        span.hr {
            width: 80px;
            height: 1px;
            background-color: #C79A79;
            display: block;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }
        div.review-content {
            p {
                font-family: $R_Regular;
                font-size: 1.07em;
                max-width: 720px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в настройке карусели и JS файла.
Решил с помощью этого кода взятого с en stackoverflow

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

// Most important owl features
items : 1,
itemsCustom : false,
itemsDesktop : [1199,1],
itemsDesktopSmall : [980,1],
itemsTablet: [768,1],
itemsTabletSmall: false,
itemsMobile : [479,1],
singleItem : false,
itemsScaleUp : false,
slideBy: 1,

//Basic Speeds
slideSpeed : 200,
paginationSpeed : 800,
rewindSpeed : 1000,

//Autoplay
autoPlay : true,
stopOnHover : false,

// Navigation
navigation : false,
rewindNav : true,
scrollPerPage : false,

//Pagination
pagination : true,
// Responsive 
responsive: true,
responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
responsiveBaseWidth: window,

})

});
```